# is there any way to copy the "Work Item Type" diagram in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, team-foundation-server

I used the Process Editor (from TFS Power Tools) to update the **Workflow diagram** of a particular Work Item Type (viz., the "Issue" type). There are a dozen other projects on our server that share the Issue type, and I would like to port my changes to all of them. But unfortunately, while the Process Editor allows you to export/import Work Item Types to/from the server, it only includes the`.xml` (definition) file, which doesn't include the workflow diagram. (The diagram is stored in the`.wit` and the`.wit.diagram` files, which do not get imported with the`.xml`). 
Is there any way to copy the diagram to all the projects?

(Note: I eventually intend to make similar changes to several of the work item types, so an automated solution to propagate these changes across all the projects would be much appreciated!)

Running TFS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

The [TFS Team Project Manager](http://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/) has a tool to sync work item definitions between team projects.

You can also use `witadmin` to export a Process Template from one Team Project and import into another without using the UI.